# I deleted my mail account, but now want access to my app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Yeah, I know, I shouldn't have deleted my account. I didn't think I would need it.

Now, someone wants my website, and it's still actively running on App Engine, I just cannot administer it. And... It actually has pretty good page rank.

Can I access my app engine admin console somehow? Or is this just a runaway site?

If I can't gain access to my site, I will ask a second question here. If I were to 301 redirect to a newly created app engine site, and just duplicated the content, would the page rank transfer to the redirect?

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: Firstly; you deleted your account. Only Google can help you get it back - ask them. Secondly, SEO is off-topic here. [webmasters.se] might help you but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: This is way off topic, but I will try to help... Please keep in mind that Stackoverflow.com is mostly for coding related problems.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/32046?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

1) Find out who the developer/admin/billing admin is for your App Engine project. You might still have an active account that can access it.

2) If you have no access, then contact Google Cloud Platform Support, only they can help you get your access back.

3) If you are redirecting from a webpage TO this "runaway" app, the page rank will not transfer over. The runaway app's domain/URL/address has the page rank.